# Do I need a special microfilter for FTTC/VDSL?

Tags: router, vdsl

My ADSL is being upgraded to FTTC/VDSL next week. I'm told that it no longer involves an engineer visit - BT are sending me a new router, and I just plug in the new router where my current ADSL router is plugged in.

I'm using a microfilter because I don't have a filtered faceplate. Do I use my existing microfilter, or do I need a new type of microfilter for FTTC/VDSL?

Extra info: I have just the one phone socket with no extensions so it's a very simple config. The existing ADSL has been working fine for several years so the existing filter is fine for ADSL.

Comment: Your existing filter should suffice for the voice line.

Answer (score 1):

#### Do I use my existing microfilter, or do I need a new type of microfilter?

Using an existing microfilter can result in much lower speeds than when a filtered faceplate is fitted.

Faceplate filters are inexpensive (£9.95 from [Amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00NBZKN30/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=6738&creativeASIN=B00NBZKN30&linkCode=as2&tag=spaldwicwebsi-21&linkId=XVSNCFDADKXIGDSL)) and will generally deliver significant improvements in broadband speeds.

---

#### Fibre Broadband (FTTC) Self Install and the Risks to Broadband Speeds Without a VDSL Faceplate Filter

> BT has recently instigated a self-install option for FTTC fibre
>   broadband where an engineer no longer needs to visit customers’
>   premises.
>
> At first sight, this new self-install option looks to provide a
>   win-win situation for broadband users and BT. Self installation will
>   be cheaper for broadband users and they no longer will need to wait in
>   for a visit from an engineer. For BT, there is a significant cost
>   saving as the engineer will no longer need to visit customers’
>   premises to fit an Openreach modem and faceplate filter. Currently,
>   the self-install option is only available for BT Infinity 1 and ‘up to
>   38 Mbps’ download services offered by other ISPs.
>
> However, there is potentially a significant downside to the
>   self-install option that broadband users need to be aware of. Self
>   installation relies on broadband users installing microfilters on
>   every telephone socket, as with the installation of conventional ADSL
>   and ADSL2+ broadband services. However, installing microfilters
>   filters can often result in much lower speeds than when a filtered
>   faceplate is fitted.
>
> The difference in speeds achieved by using a faceplate filter at the
>   BT master socket rather than microfilters will generally be much
>   larger for fibre broadband than for ADSL and ADSL2+ services.
>
> We urge anyone considering or opting for a self-install fibre
>   broadband service to install a faceplate filter. These are inexpensive
>   and will generally deliver significant improvements in broadband
>   speeds. Given the low cost of a filtered faceplate, you will still
>   save money compared with an installation by an engineer and should
>   achieve the same speeds!
>
> For simplicity, here is a link to a high-quality, low-priced VDSL
>   faceplate: [VDSL Faceplate from Amazon UK](http://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B00NBZKN30/ref=as_li_tl?ie=UTF8&camp=1634&creative=6738&creativeASIN=B00NBZKN30&linkCode=as2&tag=spaldwicwebsi-21&linkId=XVSNCFDADKXIGDSL)

Source [Fibre Broadband (FTTC) Self Install and the Risks to Broadband Speeds Without a VDSL Faceplate Filter](http://www.increasebroadbandspeed.co.uk/2014/bt-infinity-fttc-self-install)

Comment: Thanks David, though this still leaves me somewhat unsure. The opening statement implies the existing filter will work, but then it gives an example of a faceplate specific to VDSL.

Comment: @JohnRennie I assume they are talking about an existing normal faceplate with a separate ADSL filter plugged compared to the specialised VDSL faceplate (which will have a built-in filter).